# Как работает это умножение?

Tags: python

Почему на выходе создается массив с 1000 нулями? Как я это вижу: создается массив состоящий из числа. Это число умножается на 1000, получается ноль. И после этого на массив с одним нулем ссылается переменная a.

```
a = [0] * 1000
print(a)
```

Comment: `[0] * 1000` это то же самое что и `[0] + [0] + [0] + [0] + [0] + ...` (но стоит отметить, что объекты внутри списка не создаются каждый раз заново, хотя на числах это не заметно)

Comment: Это число умножается на 1000 если a = [0*1000]. А у вас на 1000 умножается список.

Comment: Это **не умножение** (как всегда, алфавита под все знаки операций не хватат, вот overloading и сбивает людей с толку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Числа в массиве умножаются на определённое, поставленное тобой число: например

```
print([2, 3, 1]*2)
```

*выведет [2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]*
То есть ты умножаешь массив на определённое число и создаёшь в том же массиве копии всех чисел массива столько раз, чему равно число, на которое ты умножаешь массив